# Grails ehcache.xml custom caches configuration

Tags: caching, grails, ehcache, grails-2.0

ehache.xml for cache configuration has been created.
But setting in this file works only for hibernate 2L cache
For custom caches  (for example caching service methods invocation: **@Cacheable('someCache')** ) cache plugin settings don't work

```
<cache name="someCache" maxElementsInMemory="100" timeToLiveSeconds="86400" timeToIdleSeconds="86400"/>
```

But if setting in Config.groovy -- it works

```
grails.cache.config = {
  cache {
    name 'someCache'
    timeToIdleSeconds 86400
    timeToLiveSeconds 86400
    maxElementsInMemory 100
  }
}
```

Like for *springcache* plugin I tried to share cacheManager

```
cacheManager(EhCacheManagerFactoryBean) {
    shared = true
}
```

Where is no result

Now I have to write configuration in two places and for cache managing use  **grailsCacheManager.cacheManager** & **CacheManager.instance**

Any ideas?

Upd:
Configuration in Config.groovy has been created

```
import  grails.test.Test
grails.cache.config = {
  domain {
    name Test
    timeToIdleSeconds 3600
    timeToLiveSeconds 3600
    maxElementsInMemory 50000
  }
  cache {
    name 'myCache'
    timeToIdleSeconds 86400
    timeToLiveSeconds 86400
    maxElementsInMemory 1000
  }
  defaults {
    eternal false
    overflowToDisk false
    diskPersistent false
    timeToIdleSeconds 600
    timeToLiveSeconds 3600
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy 'LRU'
  }
}
```

Domain:

```
package grails.test
class Test {
  static mapping = {
    cache 'nonstrict-read-write'
    version false
  }
}
```

and in controller I call:

```
Test.get(params.id)
```

**But cache is empty:**
grails.test.Test cur size:0

Custom cache "myCache" -- work

Comment: See workaround http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPCACHEEHCACHE-4

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Grails ehcache plugin [documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-cache-ehcache/guide/usage.html). It contains sections which explains how to configure the Hibernate 2nd level cache using the Grails cache plugin DSL. Look for "Hibernate second-level cache" and "Hibernate domain class second-level caches"

Comment: Problem in "Custom" cache and two cache managers. Hibernate 2nd level cache works well

Comment: Why do you need 2 cache managers? if you need one for Hibernate and one for the caches managed by the ehcache plugin then the documentation shows how to configure it using the DSL without the need for ehcache.xml

Comment: I have updated question. DSL configuration for domains cache not work.